# Rails 7 How to import pinned js modules in action's views / partial layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

i tried to import a pinned js module in an action view, but got the error related to `es-module-shims`

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
...
pin_all_from "app/javascript/zzz", under: "zzz"


# layouts/application.html.erb
...
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>


# zzz/show.html.erb
...
<%= javascript_importmap_tags("zzz") %>
...
```

then when load the show action page, sometime i got the bellow error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'application' from ... es-module-shims.js:769 

Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'zzz' from ... es-module-shims.js:769
```

It looks like the async loading `es-module-shims.js` file be broken. If i change to `javascript_importmap_tags("zzz", shim: false)`, it'll be ok, but we need `es-module-shims` for support non-Chromium browsers, right ?

so How could i import pinned js modules in action's views (or partial layouts) ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javascript_importmap_tags](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/ef8dc8297fd4760f5f8872bb98f1ea9b0c3746bf/app/helpers/importmap/importmap_tags_helper.rb#L3-L11) method code, this method will setup all script tags needed to use an importmap-powered entrypoint (which defaults to application.js) which include `es-module-shims.js` loading script, so if i call it again on action's view then there're duplicate scripts and this leads to unstable loading `es-module-shims.js`.

```rb
# https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails../importmap_tags_helper.rb
  def javascript_importmap_tags(entry_point = "application", shim: true)
    safe_join [
      javascript_inline_importmap_tag,
      javascript_importmap_module_preload_tags,
      (javascript_importmap_shim_nonce_configuration_tag if shim),
      (javascript_importmap_shim_tag if shim),
      javascript_import_module_tag(entry_point)
    ].compact, "\n"
  end
```

Actually i just only need call the method `javascript_import_module_tag` which will generate a script import my module:

```rb
# layouts/application.html.erb
...
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %> # Set up needed script and import `application`


# zzz/show.html.erb
...
<%= javascript_import_module_tag("zzz") %> # only import `zzz` module
```

Now i don't get loading `es-module-shims.js` errors anymore.