# Trying to use select2 with Importmaps on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I am trying to use Select2 on a new Rails 7 app and am struggling as follows:

I have pinned it into my import maps and imported it like so:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "trix"
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.js"
pin "select2", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.js"
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
```

(the two last lines were added when I run bin/importmap pin select2)

```
import "jquery";
import "select2";
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import "controllers";
import "trix";
import "@rails/actiontext";
```

(have moved both jquery and select2 to the end as well as to the beginning - didn't change a thing).

When I am in a form, I can access an element with $ like so:

```
$('#book_genre_ids');
...(returns the element)
```

But when I manually try - in the console - to run select2() on an element, here's what happens:

```
$('#book_genre_ids').select2();
VM574:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:22
```

I did check the network sources (chrome console), and I could find npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist and npm:select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist from gap.jspm.io.
I found some resources that pointed at multiple jquery libraries being loaded, but I didn't find more than the above in the network sources in the console...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select2 will register itself as a jQuery function `.select2()`, so in order to using this method, the `select2` lib must be loaded after the `jquery` lib, otherwise it could not find `jquery` reference, hence it could not register `jquery` function, hence the error `$(...).select2 is not a function` will be throw.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js" />
```

However, the `import` is asynchronous loading so it's not guarantee that when `select2` look for `jquery`, this lib is loaded. So although you setup import them in order as below:

```js
import "jquery";
import "select2";
```

The `select2` is still not found the `jquery` when it needed.

Fortunately, the [gem importmap-rails](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails) support preloading pin modules ([modulepreload](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/modulepreload)), so base on that i come up with a solution: preload `jquery` before `select2`

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js", preload: true
pin "select2", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"
```

Then i follow the way Rails7 setup "@hotwired/stimulus" to setup "jquery"

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/application.js
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
...
import jQuery from "jquery"
window.jQuery = jQuery // <- "select2" will check this
window.$ = jQuery
...
```

now on stimulus controllers where "select2" is needed, you could load "select2"

```js
// app/javascript/controllers/demo_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import "select2"

export default class extends Controller {
  initialize() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
  }
// ...
```

Note: your "select2" CDN "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.js" source contain `import e from"jquery";` at the first line hence it'll not work in this solution, so i recommend using the official cdn link: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" instead.

**update**

In case you don't want to use stimulus, you could pin another js file to setup "select2" and load it in your layout views

```js
// app/javascript/utils.js
import "select2"

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

```rb
# config/importmap.rb
...
pin "utils"

# app/views/products/show.html.erb
<%= javascript_import_module_tag("utils") %>
...
```

Note: you have to use `javascript_import_module_tag`, not `javascript_importmap_tags`, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71016364/rails-7-how-to-import-pinned-js-modules-in-actions-views-partial-layouts/71018519#71018519)

Comment: thanks for the exhaustive answer! I did change the importmap for jquery to preload, and I also changed the source for select2. However I am now a bit confused. I am simply trying to call select2 on a form.... in Rails 6, I would have used a special class and then via javascript used something like $('.class-name').select2() .... why would I need to load select2 on a stimulus controller?

Comment: @tkhobbes no need to use `stimulus`,  take a look at my update.

Comment: ok thanks - this worked. I now have a problem that in my form I have TWO select boxes (one triggered by select2 and one other one) but I think this is a stylesheet problem... I think I now need to import the corresponding select2 stylesheet.

Comment: Two more things worth noting: The npm version of select2 does not seem to work. As @LamPhan correctly stated, the official CDN version of select2 has to be referenced in the importmap. Also, I'm not sure whether the module preload is really required - the importmap thing may figure out that jQuery has to be loaded before select2 (for me, it works without preload: true).

Comment: To make things work even better, I want to remind you to add the CSS file of select2

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lam Phan. But it is not enough. For me, loading of select2 was resolved simple, then i'm expected. It resolved select2 initialization for development and production enviroments both.

See the `vendor/assets/javascripts` folder inside select2-rails gem. That folder contains the file `select2.js`

Add to your `app/assets/config/manifest.js` lines in such order:

```
//= link jquery.min.js
//= link select2.js
```

That is enough for me and pins and import working by default:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin 'jquery', to: 'jquery.min.js'
...
pin 'select2'
pin 'application'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript', under: 'application'
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js
import 'jquery'
...
import 'select2'
```

```
# app/views/layout/application.html.haml
...
  %head
    = javascript_importmap_tags 'application'
```

```js
// app/javascript/utils/select2_init.js
export class Select2Init {
  start() {
    $(function() {
      $('.select2').select2()
    })
  }
}
```

and run initializer in start point:

```js
import { Select2Init } from 'application/utils/select2_init'

new Select2Init().start()
```

Comment: Thank you Sergio. I actually run into so many other issues with importmaps, that I switched to jsbundling.