# What is the proper way to include the javascript library in rails 7 that doesn't have an export?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I'm having trouble with importing Jquery in rails 7 using bin/importmap. When I import the Jquery with normal script tag, the code works fine. But when I try to do it using bin/importmap in Stimulus controllers, the code throws an error.

Trying with bin/importmap:

#### importmap.rb:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
pin "fomantic-ui", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.js"
pin "nag", to: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/components/nag.min.js"
```

#### hello_controller.js

```
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import jQuery from "jquery"
let $ = jQuery;
import "fomantic-ui"
import "nag"

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        $('#fixednag').nag({
            persist: true
        });
    }
}
```

#### error

```
Failed to register controller: hello (controllers/hello_controller) ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    <anonymous> semantic.js:25
```

After adding the jquery using normal script tag and removing import $ in hello_controller.rb, it works fine:

#### application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pingcoders</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/semantic.min.css" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/components/nag.min.css" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
</head>
```

#### hello_controller.rb

```
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import "fomantic-ui"
import "nag"

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        $('#fixednag').nag({
            persist: true
        });
    }
}
```

What is the reason for the error? Is there any other way to import jQuery properly?

Comment: your error cause `fomantic-ui` require `jQuery` but it could not found that library since `import` is async loading. You have to pre-load `jquery` first before import `fomantic-ui`. The same with `select2` [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034848/trying-to-use-select2-with-importmaps-on-rails-7/71063600#71063600)

Comment: Thank you. Importing `jQuery` in the `controllers/application.js` solved the issue.